# Get firebase docs by groups using name?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement this:
get all docs by groups using name field an then get the last doc in each group,
How can I do that since firebase is NoSQL?

-here is reports collection which about doctors reports and that means any doctor can have more than one report, So i need to get last report for each doctor

Here is how my firebase data model look like:
[image: data model]

Comment: What does your existing firestore data model look like? That would help give pointed answers on whether restructuring your data model or querying your data model differently would make sense. You can edit your question to include the data model you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the last report of each doctor, the best solution is to save the report directly in the doctor's document.

And each time a doctor make a new report you **replace** the old one by the new one.